# Scheduled tasks not running on moodle

Tags: php, cron, moodle, shared-hosting, intl

When the cron job for moodle runs I get this output:

```
Execute scheduled task: Clean up ad hoc task metadata (core\task\task_lock_cleanup_task)
!!! Exception - Class 'IntlTimeZone' not found !!!

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on null in /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php:1145
Stack trace:
#0 /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php(1274): mysqli_native_moodle_database->emulate_bound_params('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#1 /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/dml/moodle_database.php(1679): mysqli_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array, 0, 0)
#2 /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/classes/lock/mysql_lock_factory.php(161): moodle_database->get_record_sql('SELECT RELEASE_...', Array)
#3 /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/classes/lock/lock.php(120): core\lock\mysql_lock_factory->release_lock(Object(core\lock\lock))
#4 /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/classes/lock/lock.php(134): core\lock\lock->release()
#5 [internal function]: core\lock\lock->__destruct()
#6 {main}
  thrown in /home/cbisacok/public_html/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 1145
```

I'm running moodle on shared hosting on namecheap. i'm on moodle version 4.1.4 and i'm using PHP Version 8.0.30 I have intl enabled in the php settings it looks like this: [image]
and here is some addtional system information:
[image]
Please let me know if there is anymore information I can add that would be helpful. This problem causes non of the sheduled tasks in moodle to run

I'm kind of at a lost on how to move forward debugging this problem...

Comment: First thing to check: Is the php-intl extension enabled for both webserver and CLI versions of PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron uses the cli version of PHP, phpinfo() uses the server/Apache version of PHP

Check if the cli version is the same (note Moodle 4.1.4 supports up to PHP 8.1 but not 8.2)

```
php -v
```

And has `intl` enabled

```
php -m
```

You can also run a scheduled task from the command line to test it, which might give you more info

https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Administration_via_command_line#Scheduled_tasks

eg:

```
php admin/cli/scheduled_task.php --showdebugging --execute='\core\task\task_lock_cleanup_task'
```

There is also a command line tool to check the status

```
php admin/cli/checks.php
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much so the version of PHP that the cron job was trying to use was verision 7. the cron was running the command like this /opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php -q /home/user/public_html/admin/cli/cron.php. but if I just ran php -v from the command line it used version 8 so I changed the cron to run the command like this:  php -q /home/user/public_html/admin/cli/cron.php and it was working for me